# Separate stream of numbers into groups of closer integers

Tags: algorithm, split, numbers

I have a stream of numbers such as

```
[2872, 2997, 3121, 13055, 14178, 14302, 23134, 23382, 23507, 32832, 33677, 34017, 43415, 44246, 44374, 52866, 54035, 54158, 62835, 64243, 64936, 73110, 73890, 74014, 82809, 83771, 83899, 93436, 94765, 94891].
```

I would like to split it as follows:

```
[[2872, 2997, 3121], [13055, 14178, 14302], [23134, 23382, 23507], [32832, 33677, 34017], [43415, 44246, 44374], [52866, 54035, 54158], [62835, 64243, 64936], [73110, 73890, 74014], [82809, 83771, 83899], [93436, 94765, 94891]].
```

It is to be noted that the distance between the groups could be closer to each other, also the digits within a group could be farther away.

Comment: Is the sequence always increasing ?

Comment: you want to group them into 3? and is the numbers are always sorted?

Comment: Do you want certain range buckets? for example 0-10000, 10000-20000 ect with the bucket size adjustable? or should it find a certain size of group or should it auto detect groups that have a maximum distance from eachother?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, numbers are always in increasing order, however group lengths could vary.

Comment: @Dinomaster there are no fixed bucket range. the groups must be auto detected based on the distance between each other. for ex: [[200, 400, 13000], [33000, 33100, 45000]]...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a way to look at your data, which should be insightful.

Original values:

[image]

Deltas:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a list of list of integers (or array of array) with size N/3 (N being the total of your numbers), and then just loop on this length and put the minimal number in it?

Something like this (I don't know what language you are using so I use c# as exemple):

```
        int len = numbersStream.count();
        List<List<int>> BigList = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> smallList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            smallList = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++i)
            {
                int value = Math.Min(numbersStream);
                smallList.Add(value);
                numbersStream.remove(value);
            }
            BigList.Add(smallList);
        }
```

BigList will be : (2872, 2997, 3121), (13055, 14178, 14302) etc...

*Assuming you always have exactly %3 numbers, otherwise you just tune the algorithm to avoid exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in java but basically what this does is find the average delta and groups everything in a subset if the difference between the two elements is smaller then that average. You can fine tune this process by changing how the averageDelta operates

ps. this solution assumes your input is at least 1 large and called temp

```
int[] diffrence = new int[temp.length-1];

for (int i=1; i < temp.length; i++) {
    diffrence[i-1] = temp[i]-temp[i-1];
}
int averageDelta = (int) Math.round(Arrays.stream(diffrence).average().orElse(1.0));

List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
currentList.add(temp[0]);

for (int i=1; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i]-temp[i-1] > averageDelta) {
        resultList.add(currentList);
        currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    currentList.add(temp[i]);
}
resultList.add(currentList);
System.out.println(resultList.toString());
```